# mysql_fetch_assoc function replacement

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

In my php code I have 2 loops and they run properly except for 1 if statment where i'm not able to replace the following function.

**(1)While this code is fine and run in the first loop**

```
if(isset($_GET['Filter']) && !empty($_GET['Filter'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE ";
    foreach( $_GET['Filter'] as $filter ){
        $query .= "$filter='y' AND ";
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -5);
}

while($data = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    //echo $data
}
```

**(2)this other one gives an sql error**

```
if(isset($_GET['Filter']) && !empty($_GET['Filter'])){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE" );
    foreach( $_GET['Filter'] as $filter ){
        $sql .=("$filter='y' ORDER BY RegularPrice ASC LIMIT 1 AND ");
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -5);
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    //echo $row
}
```

Can anybody help me to find eventual syntax error in the (2) second if statment I have posted?

Comment: What are you attempting with the `substr`? You already run the original SQL command with `mysql_query`, and appending more SQL (and then less) to the result resource won't work.

Comment: I have got this code with substr here on this site and believe it works only like this:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second query, you are assigning partial `mysql_query()` to the variable `$sql`, then you concatenate strings to it. I assume this is a mistake and you simply want to assign the string `SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE` to the variable `$sql`.

Also, notice the string you are concatenting:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE" );
foreach( $_GET['Filter'] as $filter ){
    $sql .=("$filter='y' ORDER BY RegularPrice ASC LIMIT 1 AND ");
}
```

This will produce something like:

`SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE filter1='y' ORDER BY RegularPrice ASC LIMIT 1 AND filter2='y' ORDER BY RegularPrice ASC LIMIT 1 AND filter3='y' ORDER BY RegularPrice ASC LIMIT 1 AND`

which is an invalid SQL query.

What you want to try instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE ";
foreach( $_GET['Filter'] as $filter ){
    $sql .= "$filter='y' AND ";
}
$sql = substr($query, 0, -5); // Remove the last ' AND '
$sql .= " ORDER BY RegularPrice ASC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query ($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `mysql_query(`

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE" );
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE";
```

as it is in the top one... that is a function that executes the query - which I'm quite sure you don't want to do yet.

Also, by the way, in your sample code - neither really execute the query properly - and so the fetch_assoc calls wouldn't work (I assume you just sanitised them out.)

Cheers